# Show that there exists a vector $v$ such that $Av\neq 0$ but $A^2v=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $4\times 4$ matrix over $\mathbb C$ such that $rank A=2$ and $A^3=A^2\neq 0$.Suppose that $A$ is not diagonalisable. Then

Show that there exists a vector $v$ such that $Av\neq 0$ but $A^2v=0$

**My try**:$\dim \operatorname{Im}(A)+\dim \ker (A)=4$ so $\dim(\ker A)=\dim (\operatorname{Im}A)=2$.

Now $A$ satisfies $x^3=x^2\implies x^2(x-1)=0$ thus $0,1$ are the only eigen values of $A$. Since $A$ has rank $2$ so geometric multiplicity of $0$ is $2$ but $A$ is not diagonalizable thus algebraic multiplicity of $0$ is $3$.

So the characteristic polynomial will be $x^4-x^3=0$

Obviously $A$ will have a Jordan block of size $2$ corresponding to 0

$$\   A  \text{ will have Jordan form as } \pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0}  
$$

How should I use these  information to conclude my result??

Comment: Your $A$ has rank $3$, one of the $1$s on the diagonal ought to be a $0$.

Comment: Some related posts:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086438/true-or-false-statement-about-a-non-diagonal-matrix
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311834/characteristic-polynomial-of-a-complex-4-by-4-matrix

Answer (score 1):

There are only two possible Jordan forms: 
$$\pmatrix{0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1}, \quad \pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&1}$$ only the first first one satisfies $A^2 = A^3.$

$\bf p.s.$

the nonzero vector $v$ you are looking for is in $\ker(A^2)\setminus \ker(A)$ we have $dim(\ker(A^2) = 3,dim(\ker(A) = 2.$

step 1.  find a basis of $3$ vector for $ker(A^2)$ by row reducing $A$ if you must.

step 2. find the vector $v$ in the basis so that $Av \neq 0.$

Comment: Are you sure these are only two ?What about mine? But how to find $v$

Comment: @learnmore   your matrix is similar to the first one on my list. both have $2,1$ block corresponding to the zero eigenvalue and $1$ block corresponding to the eigenvalue $1.$

Comment: But you did not say how to find $v$

Comment: @learnmore, see my edit.

Comment: but what made you think that such a vector exists ?Is it very normal to find that i cant see or requires some effort

Comment: @learnmore, of course it requires effort on your part and a particular matrix $A.$

Comment: i.e my question sir!! how did you see it?

Comment: @learnmore, did you read my postscript. it gives you an algorithm  to find a $v$ if you have a matrix satisfying the hypothesis. i don't know what you mean by see it? what is it?

Comment: when we try to  solve the problem we first make sure that it is solvable ;we try to guess why it is true and then solve it by giving concrete arguements by "see it" I mean why you thought that such $v$ should exist ;did you see that from rank of $A$ being 2 or some other hypothesis

Comment: @learnmore,yes. the reason such a $v$ exists is that $dim(\ker(A)) = 2$ and $dim(\ker(A^2)) = 3.$ that $\ker(A^2)$ has dimension one bigger than the dimension $\ker(A)$ makes it possible for such a $v$ to exist.