# Characteristic polynomial of a complex 4 by 4 matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $4 \times 4$ matrix over $C$ such that $rank (A)=2$ and $A^3=A^2 \neq 0.$  Suppose that $A$ is not diagonalizable. Then prove that there exist a vector $v$ such that $Av$ is not equal to zero, but $A^2v=0$
and the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $x^4-x^3$.

Comment: Some related posts:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086438/true-or-false-statement-about-a-non-diagonal-matrix
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295229/show-that-there-exists-a-vector-v-such-that-av-neq-0-but-a2v-0